# Google Charts: "(NaN,NaN,NaN") is not a valid RGB color

Tags: javascript, charts

I recently started getting this error when attempting to load Google Charts. The relevant section of my project where it occurs is this:

```
<script>

    function initGoogleServices() {
        console.log('Google', 'Loading Google services');
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart', 'line', 'calendar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
            console.log('Google', 'Done loading charts')
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initGoogleServices"></script>
```

I have taken a variety of courses to try and determine if it is a problem with the rest of my code or not, but nothing resolves it:

1. I have removed all non-Google CSS and JS
2. I have removed all markup
3. Cleared cache, etc.

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alright, here's a lead: removing `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initGoogleServices` and just running the init code in its own `script` tags after `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js` seems to resolve this. Has there been recent changes introducing a collision between these libs maybe? I have been using the setup in the question for months without problems.

Comment: Update: so apparently this workaround was not permanent. Problem is back even if I do not add the other lib. Meh.

Comment: Update2: this seems to be a Chrome issue, it is not reproducible on Firefox. Confirmed on both Linux and OSX so far.

Comment: Update3: it could also somehow be related to the fact that our dev environment runs on localhost. The problem does not occur on our production server under any browser.

Comment: I started getting this problem today.  And it's working on one of our VM when we load the same webpage. but other machines are having this error. I've check the browser version on each machine and they are all running the latest Chrome.

Comment: @NPToita can you confirm that this is only a Chrome issue on your side? We are not getting it in any other browser.

Comment: It seems that the error was coming from the "calendar" library.  remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: you'd get the same error when you browse to google's documentation page for the calendar extension: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar